# Как считать файл по строкам?

Tags: php

Получаю текст в одну строку, а их в файле 4. Добавляю тег `<bg>` и получаю кракозябры, а также каждая буква выводится с новой строки.
Хочу еще разделить строки по четным и нечетным, но нужно с этой проблемой разобраться.

```
$f = fopen('test.txt','r');
while (!feof($f)){
    echo fgetc($f)."<br>";
}
fclose($f)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно выводить так:

```
Advertisers study how people
If an advert can achieve this
If an advert works well, the
If advertisements are to he
```

Comment: Чего вы в итоге хотите добиться и что не получается?

Comment: Целыми строками в столбик как в файле, а не по 1 букве

Comment: у вас учебная задача или нет? Если нет, то `$lines = file("test.txt")`; _кракозябры_ у вас там от BOM небось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fgetc()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetc.php) считывает символ, а не строку. Используйте [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgets.php):

```
$f = fopen('test.txt','r');
while (!feof($f))
{
    echo fgets($f)."<br>";
}
fclose($f);
```

**UPD:** вариант с разделением строк на четные и нечетные:

```
$f = fopen('test.txt','r');
$n = 1;
$arr1 = $arr2 = array();
while(!feof($f))
{
    if($n%2!=0)
        $arr1[] = fgets($f);
    else
        $arr2[] = fgets($f);
    $n++;
}
fclose($f);
var_dump($arr1);
var_dump($arr2);
```

Comment: перепутал fgets и fgetc

Comment: @Andrii если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте ответ принятым. Для этого [нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

как вариант, если задача не академическая

```
$lines = file("test.txt");
```

разделение на четные и нечетные строки:

```
$odd = array_filter($lines, function($k){ return $k % 2; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```